# Run CodedUI test using xUnit

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests, xunit

I'm trying to run a CodedUI-related test using xUnit instead of MsTest.
This results in

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies

If I switch back to MsTest everything works fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check your References for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework`, and also your `using` block for `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;`

If those don't exist, first add the `using` statement, then rebuild your solution. If you are still having the error, right click on References -> Add Reference. Then search for `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll`. If it doesn't come up in the list, click Browse and navigate to where the .dll is located. For me it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll`. Select the .dll -> click Add -> Ok, then rebuild your solution again.

If you create a solution with `Unit Test Project` (or anything other than `CodedUI Test Project`), then you need to add the .dll and `using` statement.

Comment: This results in Null Reference Exception when trying to locate a control. Do you have a working sample with CodedUI and xUnit test?

Comment: I do not have a working sample, and I unfortunately I do not have information about your situation to give a more detailed response. That being said, it sounds like adding the reference solved your initial problem of the library not being recognized. The current problem - a null reference exception - unfortunately does not reveal enough to give a diagnosis. If you could provide some more detailed information/code where the error is thrown/error message, that would help provide some clarity :)

Comment: Checkout this repo https://github.com/LogoFX/Samples.Specifications.
Use EndToEnd-CodedUI branch
Select 'EndToEndWithFake' build configuration
Build the solution
Run any test (either via Resharper or Test Explorer or command line)
Observe the exception(s)

Comment: Thanks Gena, but can you just post the relevant portion(s) of you code? trying to debug your entire project is a big commitment :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for your help. First of, you don't have to debug the entire project. It fails right at the start. Second of, the relevant portion is with the Specs project. I also tried creating a new CodedUI Test project and decorating with the CodedUITest attribute an xUnit class. It doesn't work either...

Comment: Perfect! An MVP project is much easier to deal with. I looked over your repo and its just too much to try to work with in this context. Please post the code you used with this new mini project. Please also mention what you used to run the project. I suspect either a problem with your runner not knowing what to do with CodedUI. Or if you are still having null reference issues with a CodedUI class, maybe there's a naming conflict between the libraries that needs explicit declaration, and it's throwing an error as a result